# What is the name of this tool?

Tags: tools

I see these all the time, but don't know the name of this wrench tool. Anyone know?
[image]

Answer (score 6):

Metric multi-size bolt head rounder-offer

Comment: LOL, I usually see these associated with a bike repair kit. Easy all size nut/bolt wrench.

Comment: If it is a bike wrench, the slightly curved tip is the tire tool.

Answer (score 0):

It's a proprietary multi-size hex wrench. Like commenters have said, it's often associated with bicycle or motorcycle toolkits.

[10 in 1 Bike Bicycle Cycling Mini Flat Hexagon Wrench Multi Functions Steel Hexagon Spanner Repair Hand Tool DIY Hex Key](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/10-in-1-Bike-Bicycle-Cycling-Mini-Flat-Hexagon-Wrench-Multi-Functions-Steel-Hexagon-Spanner-Repair/32696534142.html?spm=2114.40010708.4.113.VMJgeJ&aff_platform=aaf&cpt=1487041027528&sk=zj6qB6AIM&aff_trace_key=2b490f935d5f405f9610d3ffb662a727-1487041027528-07538-zj6qB6AIM)

Comment: I figured as much. Just couldnt find this specific one online anywhere. Thanks for the feedback yall!

Comment: Votes are better than chatty comments. (We're not really a discussion forum.) :)